# Azure Devops Services - Change Team project from one hosted process to another

Tags: azure-devops

everybody.

We have just successfully migrated from ADServer 2019 to ADServices.

We have a single custom process template that is used for all Team Projects.  After migration, each team project has its own Process Template, as expected.

However, as all migrated Process Templates are equal,  I would like to group all Team Projects in a single Process Template.

In order to do that, I do these steps:

- Go to Organization Settings
- Select Process
- Click on one of my hosted process templates
- Click on "Projects"
- Click on "..."  and select "Change Process"
- A pop up appears, where I can select the target process I like to change. It's important to note that all hosted migrated process seems to be avaliable for the change.
- When I select another hosted process, and click "Ok", the message "The feature is disabled. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator." appears and the change can't be done.

I have been looking how to enable this feature with no success.

Has anyone had this situation?

If is not possible to do that, is there any way to import the future changes of my process template via command line, in order to update all my team projects ?

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards,

Alba

Comment: If you create a new team project, are you able to change the process?

Comment: Any update to your issue?

Comment: If I create a new team project based on one on the hosted process template and I try to change to another hosted process template, the behavior is the same. It appears the same message.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the `Process` website in your original post?

Answer (score 1):

We evaluated this situation with MS and the answer is that there is no way to make this change of process template between team projects belonging to different hosted process template, even though the process templates are equals.

As we cannot change our Process Template to hosted process by now, our solution was making a script using AD api, in order to make a bulk update of all process templates for all our team projects.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/processes/import%20process%20template?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, you were trying to change the process used by the team project from a hosted xml to an inherited process. For your scenario, you need to

1. [cloned your Hosted XML process to an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/upgrade-hosted-to-inherited?view=azure-devops).

[image]

2. [Change a project from Hosted XML to an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-from-hosted-to-inherited?view=azure-devops).

[image]

An useful blog for your reference:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/moving-from-hosted-xml-process-to-inherited-process-ga/

Comment: The user is Project Collection Administrator. I can change projects belonging to inherited processes

Comment: Sorry for late response. As there is no notification for your update, I missed your follow-up. Please check my updated reply.